# append new item to an array of a class in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, class, append, swift2

This is driving me crazy. I used "append" all the time, but I really can't find the problem this time. Whenever I add a new item to the array, then all elements remain the same, equal to the last appended element.
What am I missing? I am sure it must be something very simple...

```
  var MyDatabase : [MyClass] = []

    class MyClass : NSObject {
        var x : String = ""
    }

    let Item = MyClass()
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){

        Item.x = "\(i)"
        MyDatabase.append(Item)
        print(MyDatabase.first!.x) // it shows 0,1,2,3,4 and it should always be "0"
    }
    for (var i = 0 ; i < MyDatabase.count ; i++){
    print(MyDatabase[i].x) // it shows 4,4,4,4,4 and it should be 0,1,2,3,4
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin R!

Answer (score 5):

Because,Swift Class is reference type,you just add 5 reference which point to same object

Change it to this to create 5 object

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
    var x : String = ""
}

var MyDatabase : [MyClass] = []

for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    let Item = MyClass()
    Item.x = "\(i)"
    MyDatabase.append(Item)
}
print(MyDatabase.first!.x) // 0
```

Swift struct is value type,

```
struct MyClass {
    var x : String = ""
}

var MyDatabase : [MyClass] = []
var Item = MyClass()

for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    Item.x = "\(i)"
    MyDatabase.append(Item)
    print(MyDatabase.first!.x) // 0 0 0 0 0 
}
```